# Compressing a list of integers and strings into file with Python

Tags: python, compression, binaryfiles

I have a list that is made of strings made up from "A" and "B", and integers withing range 0..255. For instance array can look like this:

```
L = ["ABA", 2, 3, 100, 1, "BB"]
```

I want to put it in file as a purpose of compression (list L is the end product of BWT+MTF+Run-length transformations). I also want to read it from that file. This is what i have tried with bytearray, but since "BB" is not one byte, it fails:

```
def compresslist(L, filename):

f = open(filename, 'wb')
f.write(bytearray(L))
f.close()
```

Comment: how about [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)?
You can use it as follows: pickle.dump(L, filehandle)

Comment: Trying it right now.

Comment: There is a problem with pickle, because it adds some characters, and new spaces, so i actually increase the file size by 3, and my goal is to compress.

Comment: The file size is multiplicated by 3. As the answer says i am trying to store it as bytes, which will i guess be more efficient.

Comment: @EVR - pickle uses serializing and de-serializing, which means data has to be prepended with some extra information, like the length of the strings for example.

Comment: Yes, thanks for mentioning it, anyway, as i am compressing, extra data is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

> strings made up from "A" and "B"
>
> `L = ["ABA", 2, 3, 100, 1, "BB"]`

A simple compression for `"ABAA"` would be to use 1 bit per character: 0 for `'A'` and 1 for `'B'`

If the strings never become longer than 8, they can be stored in 1 `byte`. This would only work if the structure of your list is fixed, i.e. you know where the `bytes` and the `integers` are.

If the `integers` were all smaller than 128, `strings` (max 7 chars) could be stored in 7 bits, with the most significant bit to indicate it's a compressed string.

Comment: Yes, you are right, integers should be smaller than 128, since maximal integer number corresponds to the number of different characters in text, so if this is .txt file, that should be fine.  But i cannot guarantee strings will never be longer than 8. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mATHADDICT - Can there be more chacracters than A and B?

Comment: Ah, ok , found a way, i can just split the string into strings with max 7 chars, it will be bijective, thanks

Comment: @mATHADDICT - Somehow, you'll have to know te length of the strings too of course, to know how many bits are used for the string, when reading the data in.

Comment: Well if i map the strings to 128-255, one byte will be used. I mean if i have ABABAAAAAAAAAAA i will split it to AAAAAAA and BABAAAA and A, so 3 bytes?

Comment: @mATHADDICT - Yes, but when reading the data, will you know how many chars there are/were in the 3rd byte? (maybe from an integer that is stored already? That would be great then).

Comment: From list [1,100,2,"AA",4,"ABABAAAAAAAAAAA"], i will make list [1,100,"AA",4,"A","BABAAAA","AAAAAAA"] which will then map to [1,100,130,4,128,somenumber,somenumber] and then will be stored as bytes. I think i forgot to tell one thing, ABABABABA strings represent the length of arrays of 0, so there wont be 2 strings one next to another.

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate your help

Comment: @mATHADDICT - Glad it worked out - don't forget to vote and/or accept the answer if it helped solve your problem :)